# Convert text into HTML elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html file looks like this:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="div-sample"></div>
```

I have a text file which has the following text:

```
<b>abracadabra</b>
```

Now after reading the file from an ajax request(via a php script which just reads the file), when I write the following jQuery code:

```
$('#myDiv').innerHTML = text;
```

inspite of showing **abracadabra** it showing with the tags.

what is going on here?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/)

Comment: `$('#myDiv').html(text);`

Comment: make sure your php script that reads the file doesn't `addslashes()` or `htmlentities()` before returning the text

Comment: Not working. Infact, where the line in my text file was,
 `<ol><li>asd</li><li>asa</li></ol>`,

when i console it, I am getting: 
`&lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt;asd&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;asa&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;`

Comment: `text.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>')`?

Comment: @palaѕн you broke the question by "fixing" the code!!!

Comment: @D.Coder Please UPDATE THE QUESTION instead of posting unformatted code into a comment. Click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - `$('#myDiv').innerHTML` is in any case wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line `var text = '<b>abracadabra</b>'` sets the variable `text` to be equal to the string with the open and closing tags.

The second line sets the contents of the `$('#myDiv')` to be equal to that variable `'<b>abracadabra</b>'`. Because they are valid html tags they get parsed and this is why you don't see them in the browser.

When you log the content of the variable `text` you get it's value not parsed by the browser with the tags which is `'<b>abracadabra</b>'`